# HighWaterNumberOfObjects/Handles meaning?

Tags: windows, kernel, shared-object

I've been looking at some kernel debugging and came to see this:

```
0: kd> dt nt!_OBJECT_TYPE ffffd0851aad6c90
   +0x000 TypeList         : _LIST_ENTRY [ 0xffffd085`1aad6c90 - 0xffffd085`1aad6c90 ]
   +0x010 Name             : _UNICODE_STRING "Process"
   +0x020 DefaultObject    : (null) 
   +0x028 Index            : 0x7 ''
   +0x02c TotalNumberOfObjects : 0xa2
   +0x030 TotalNumberOfHandles : 0x553
   +0x034 HighWaterNumberOfObjects : 0xfc
   +0x038 HighWaterNumberOfHandles : 0xbf5
   +0x040 TypeInfo         : _OBJECT_TYPE_INITIALIZER
   +0x0b8 TypeLock         : _EX_PUSH_LOCK
   +0x0c0 Key              : 0x636f7250
   +0x0c8 CallbackList     : _LIST_ENTRY [ 0xffffa38f`ff5e94f0 - 0xffffa38f`ff3ae580 ]
```

Most I can understand, or figure out what they suppose to mean.
I have no idea what HighWater means, and how it differs from the TotalNumberOfObjects/Handles. 
Just from weird curiosity, any one has any idea what does it mean?

Comment: (assumption) HighWaterX means the highest value X ever archived. Like the flood-markings which can be seen on buildings close to the water.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really RE, but this likely means "the highest number of objects/handles ever seen" (in this session).
From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_water_mark):

> A high water mark is a point that represents the maximum rise of a
>   body of water over land. Such a mark is often the result of a flood,
>   but high water marks may reflect an **all-time high**, an annual high
>   (highest level to which water rose that year) or the high point for
>   some other division of time.